# Can I filter the same data differently in two columns in an Excel pivot table?

Tags: filtering, excel-2010, pivot-table

I've created a pivot table that lists the number of cases submitted by a series of locations.

Consider:

```
Location A        100
Location B         10
Location C       1000
TOTAL            1110
```

Our data for the table includes `location` and `status`. Now the client wants to see a percentage of CLOSED cases as a third column.

Consider:

```
Location A        100   50%   (based on 50 cases marked as "closed")
Location B         10   10%   (based on  1 case marked as "closed")
Location C       1000   20%   (based on 200 cases marked as "closed")
TOTAL            1110   23%   (based on 251 total cases marked as "closed")
```

I can add a third column to the table, but the second I filter on CLOSED cases, column two lists the totals of closed cases only, and my percentage is 100% for all of column three. Is there a way to leave column 2 selecting EVERYTHING, but set column one to look ONLY as closed cases?

In a perfect world, I could display `location`, `count of ALL cases by location` and `count of CLOSED cases by location, expressed as a percentage of column #2`

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to add a column to your source data that assigns a 0 for open stores and a 1 for closed. Then using my dictum:

> The percentage of True items in a list is the average of zeros and
>   ones, where True is represented by 1 and False by 0.

from [this post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/percent-of-true-items-in-a-pivot-table-field/), you can do this:

[image]

Comment: That is one of the most inventive Excel hacks I've seen in years. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! I generally try to fix the source data as much as possible before pivoting.

Comment: I feel your pain. Been doing that for about two weeks. And then finding ONE more anomalous record when I pivot. Argh. C'est la vie...comes with the territory. :)